# Does the energy output of a piezoelectric material increase when its dielectric constant is incressed?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, crystals, piezoelectric

According to the output voltage equation, the output of a piezoelectric material increases when its dielectric constant is increased. But it reduces the coupling constant. Since that can we directly say the behavior of piezoelectricity with respect to the dielectric constant?